# Grover's algorithm not under an oracle?

Tags: grovers-algorithm, oracles

I've learned about Grover's algorithm's optimal procedure, but I just read this blurb from wikipedia:

> Grover's algorithm is optimal up to sub-constant factors. That is, any algorithm that accesses the database only by using the operator $U_ω$ must apply $U_ω$ at least a $1 − o(1)$ fraction as many times as Grover's algorithm.

This gets me wondering: are there other ways to represent a search problem on quantum computers, not using this oracle method? Something that gives us more information than just a query?